# Python - Replacing repeating elements in a list with unique elements from another lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to assign unique colour values to each repeating element in a list. For this I have two different lists, one being the list which contains the repeating values (eg. `labels = [1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 12, 13, 17]`).

The second list (or list of list) contains the hue information itself:
`group_pal = seaborn.husl_palette(len(set(labels)), s=.45)`.
The key here is that the length of `group_pal` is always the number of unique elements in `labels`.

Is there a python one liner to perform this operation ?

Input:

```
labels = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3]
group_pal = sns.husl_palette(len(set(labels)), s=.45)
```

Desired output:

```
labels = mapingMacro(labels, group_pal)
labels:
[0.8167028311697733, 0.5345122109266688, 0.5750280113923723]
[0.8167028311697733, 0.5345122109266688, 0.5750280113923723]
[0.8167028311697733, 0.5345122109266688, 0.5750280113923723]
[0.7256380093027939, 0.5865684184445076, 0.45124969098702544]
[0.7256380093027939, 0.5865684184445076, 0.45124969098702544]
[0.601243246823196, 0.6281411529879642, 0.44959498566071004]
[0.46712078684915886, 0.6454760674453914, 0.6277122757100324]
```

Comment: So you just want `[group_pal[i] for i in labels]`?

Comment: @JackMoody That work for now, but with a list `labels` like even: `[3,3,3,2,2,1,0]` won't work as expected.

Comment: @U9-Forward I’m a bit confused. Why wouldn’t it work for that list?

Comment: @JackMoody Because your simply getting the values with the element as the index, so if the first one is the last one, it wouldn't work.

Comment: @JackMoody Try it. and see

Comment: @U9-Forward I tried it and it seems to work as I would expect. If `labels = [3,3,3,2,2,1,0]`, is the end goal not to return a list that is equivalent to `[group_pal[3], group_pal[3], ..., group_pal[1], group_pal[0]]`? Maybe I am misunderstanding OP's question?

Comment: @JackMoody, I agree. On a low level, that is what I want to archive. But your approach won't work on cases where the array (`labels`) itself contains something like float.

Comment: @Siddharth your question didn’t mention using floats. But if there were floats you could use `int()`.

Comment: @JackMoody, you are correct, my bad. But int(2.4) will be same as int(2.6) - and if there are repeating 2.4s and 2.6s, they all will be assigned same colour.

Comment: @Siddharth you’re right. I don’t think it would make sense to have labels that are floats that aren’t something like `1.0` or `2.00` if you are referring to an index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
group_pal = [i for x,y in zip(sns.husl_palette(len(set(labels)), s=.45),
                              sorted(set(labels),key=labels.index)) 
             for i in np.repeat([x],labels.count(y),axis=0).tolist()]
```

And now:

```
print(group_pal)
```

Is:

```
[[0.8167028311697733, 0.5345122109266688, 0.5750280113923723],
 [0.8167028311697733, 0.5345122109266688, 0.5750280113923723], 
 [0.8167028311697733, 0.5345122109266688, 0.5750280113923723], 
 [0.601243246823196, 0.6281411529879642, 0.44959498566071004], 
 [0.601243246823196, 0.6281411529879642, 0.44959498566071004], 
 [0.46712078684915886, 0.6454760674453914, 0.6277122757100324], 
 [0.6254162090818173, 0.5854245228463807, 0.7893617517727602]]
```